# I would like to get only the contents of an index which I created in AWS elasticsearch without json key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I need the content of a json data indexed in AWS elastic search without getting Json key(when the indexid is provided)

I have tried filter_path to get the source content. But it has the key of the json content. I need only the value to be displayed and not the whole content from ._source
For eg:

my indexing API is this:

```
es_enpoint/mysite/_doc/1

{"_index":"mysite","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_version":3,"found":true,"_source":{"description": {"our world needs more trees"}}
```

I tried this:

```
es_enpoint/mysite/_doc/1?filter_path=_source
```

got result:

```
{"_source":{"description": {"our world needs more trees"}}
```

But my expected result is:

```
{"our world needs more trees"}
```

without any other parameters. Can some one help on this?

Comment: Please format your code respecting StackOverflow conventions. Either you use
 "``` 
CODE 
```"
Or you have to indent your code by four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow

Here is what you are looking for !! the [official documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source)

For Elastic 6

> Use the /{index}/{type}/{id}/_source endpoint to get just the _source
>   field of the document, without any additional content around it

For Elastic 7

> Use the /{index}/_source/{id} endpoint to get just the _source field
>   of the document, without any additional content around it.

**The endpoint changed with elastic7 and removal of types**

So in your case, you should try

```
es_enpoint/mysite/_doc/1/_source?_source=description
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there a way to avoid this "description" parameter also.. I mean just this {"our world needs more trees"} alone in output?

Comment: I tried using inputting it without "description" key, but the the result had "_source" in it? can we avoid all these from output?

Comment: I dont think you can avoid the description key. Document _source is always a json object.